# How to detect if a new Wlan/Lan connection is established? PC

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

How can I detect if my system has received a new IP address?

My program reads all local IPs over `DNS.GetHostAddress` and binds a socket on each one. After a suspend, however, I cannot connect to my program.

Is there an event in `System.Net` to notify me when a system received a new IP address? My current idea for a workaround is an extra thread that checks the current interfaces.

Comment: You probably want to detect that you have gone into or out of standby mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event.

Have a look here:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged.aspx

Would be interesting to see if this works.  Looks promising.

If not, you may want to poll every n seconds, not pretty but I doubt if n is a reasonable level, it will have much of a performance impact?

Comment: thanks, this Looks like the Event i was  looking for. I will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be hardware. Does this happen if your computer is plugged in via ethernet or wifi? Does the problem occur both ways?

I would try both Ethernet and wifi, putting the computer to hibernate and then checking if you still have the problem.